# Proguard returned with error code 1. See console Error: Unknown option '(' in argument number 12

Tags: android, eclipse

While exporting my Android Application from Eclipse IDE, I am getting errors as below:

```
[2016-02-27 11:15:34 - Zip_Screen_Lock] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2016-02-27 11:15:34 - Zip_Screen_Lock] Error: Unknown option '(' in argument number 12
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.homeapps.screenlock.zipper.BootCompleteReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**bin - proguard.txt**

```
# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:48
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity { <init>(...); }

# view res/layout/screen_lock.xml #generated:58
# view res/layout/setting.xml #generated:25
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView { <init>(...); }

# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:66
-keep class com.homeapps.screenlock.zipper.BootCompleteReceiver { <init>(...); }

# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:63
-keep class com.homeapps.screenlock.zipper.LockScreenService { <init>(...); }

# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:44
-keep class com.homeapps.screenlock.zipper.ScreenLockActivity { <init>(...); }

# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:34
-keep class com.homeapps.screenlock.zipper.Setting { <init>(...); }

# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:54
-keep class com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity { <init>(...); }

# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:51
-keep class com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity { <init>(...); }
```

**proguard.cfg**

```
# Android application template

# Remove all the injar/outjar/libraryjar junk, the android ant script takes care of this

-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# Keep fragments

-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment

# Serializables

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    !private <fields>;
    !private <methods>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

# Native Methods

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Android Support Library

-keep class android.** {*;}

# Button methods

-keepclassmembers class * {

public void *ButtonClicked(android.view.View);

}

# Reflection




# Remove Logging
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** wtf(...);
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

I have added dontwarn and dontnote statements to proguard confing file with that I resolved few warnings but Not able to solve remaining issue.Please help me to solve this.Thanks you.